# Why doesn't the following method produce potential heap pollution?

Tags: java, enums

Java 7

I wrote this:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> List<SelectItem> getSelectItemList(Enum<E>... es){
    List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    for(Enum<E> e : es){
        items.add(new SelectItem(e, e.toString()));
    }
    return items;
}
```

and this method compiled with no warning. Why? I expected that such using of varargs of a generic type (which is actually an array) produces

`Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter es`

Couldn't you explain it?

Comment: It's not an array of `E` but an array of enums with the generic type `E`.

Answer (score 2):

Varargs of non - reifiable types tend to work like this. `Enum<E> ...` is effectively evaluated as `Enum[]` at runtime. At this point you can't be sure what references might get into the array.

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html

The `Enum` base type will actually give you some type - safety, even in compile time, so I guess this is why you are safe.